# Starting a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox on Fedora Workstation 21 Fails

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I would like to install the Windows 10 Tech Preview in a Virtual Machine on a computer using Fedora Workstation 21 64 bit as the host operating system. I have installed VirtualBox and created a new Virtual Machine. I am ready to install Windows 10 on the machine, but cannot because every time I try to start the machine, I get the following two errors:

[image: VirtualBox Error 1]

[image: VirtualBox Error 2]

The second error always appears after I close the first one. As is instructed by the second error message, I have tried executing both `sudo yum install kmod-VirtualBox-$(uname -r) kmod-VirtualBox` and `sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service` and neither of them have resolved the problem. I have also tried restarting the computer, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if vboxdrv is loaded (this is a kernel module, so you have to use

```
lsmod | grep vboxdrv
```

If it's not there, try to start it manually:

```
modprobe vboxdrv
```

and start virtualbox again. In some situations, it seems vboxdrv is not loaded by the operating system. I don't know how to solve that in Fedora though. It could be in a blacklist, stopping it from being loaded.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have resolved the problem. Restarted the system after running these two commands, and it appears that everything is working just fine now without me needing to run these commands. How did you know that this would resolve the problem?

Comment: I seem to have bad luck: I encountered the same problem exactly :-)

Comment: Well, thank you. I hope that this problem does not return when I install Fedora 22 Workstation in several weeks.

Comment: Bad news. Just upgraded to Fedora 22 Workstation today since it just came out, and the problem has returned. Not sure how to fix it this time.

Comment: If the above doesn't solve your problem, it's a new problem, and I'd suggest you post a new question, with any (error) messages your can find. Refer to this question, and that the problem seems different from it.

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem using the information provided here after several tries.

Comment: Great! Onward to Fedora 23 ;)

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!